# Can't Create The Same Table Twice in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

i have a C# Windows Form Application. I push a button it should create a Table and insert a value (int).
I create the initial database as a Service-Database (Add New Item > Data > Service-Database).

The code for the button is  (output follows below it):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();

    try
    {
        thisConnection.Open();

        nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable1 (intColumn int)";
        Console.WriteLine(nonqueryCommand.CommandText);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows Affected is: {0}", nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());

        nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable1 VALUES (99)";
        Console.WriteLine(nonqueryCommand.CommandText);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows Affected is: {0}",
           nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        thisConnection.Close();  // close connection
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed.");
    }
}
```

> OUTPUT:
>   CREATE TABLE MyTable1 (intColumn int)
>   Number of Rows Affected is: -1
>   INSERT INTO MyTable1 VALUES (99)
>   Number of Rows Affected is: 1
>   Connection Closed.

Nothing Shows up on Server Explorer Though No additional Tables even if I close it down and reconnect.

If i push the button to make it issue the same again i get:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'MyTable1' in the database.
```

but still nothing on server explorer.

Comment: IS THERE SOME REASON THAT YOU ARE YELLING?

Answer (score 5):

The exception told you exactly what's going on. Your table already exists. You can't create it again. You need to DROP the table if it already exists.

Comment: I think his complaint is that the table DOESN'T seem to exist in some fashion (he can't discover it with his SQL client).

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing Shows up on Server Explorer Though No additional Tables even if I close it down and reconnect.

Whenever you execute your program, Visual Studio's project management automatically deploy (copy that database) .mdf database file at deployment folder **Debug\Bin**. I think your code uses a database which is located at **Debug\Bin** folder (which will be not shown in server explorer) and **Server Explorer** shows a database (.mdf) which is located at root of project folder and it is empty.

Comment: so how do you check what the Databse is doing ?

Comment: @Richard : I've guess from your problem description. Please verify your connection string and I'm sure that the connectionString in your app.config file uses |DataDirectory| substitute.

Comment: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\WikiTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

Comment: You have two databases - first one is placed under your project folder and it is empty. Second database is copied under Debug\Bin and is used by your code. Use absolute path of project folder database in "connectionstring". e.g. ...AttachDbFilename=c:\folder\project_folder\WikiTest.mdf;..

Answer (score -2):

Try spceifying the commandType property of the SqlCommand = `CommandType.Text`

Also make sure that you are connecting to the same instance of SQL. You can get your code's by breakpointing the line after you open the connection (for it's when you know it works) and going looking for the servername.

Note that you can have multiple SQL instances in one machine... so you could be working on the right server (say localhost) and yet not be accessing the correct instance (say SQLEXPRESS instead of MSSQLSERVER).

Comment: -1: How will that help? It executed correctly the first time he clicked the button.